# Overloaded 'dereference' or 'member of pointer' operators don't get run when I have a pointer to an object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, indirection

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    int i_;
};

class El : protected Base {
public:
    int get_i() const { return i_; }
    void set_i(int i) { i_ = i; }
};

class It : protected Base {
public:
    using pointer = const El*;
    using reference = const El&;

    reference operator*() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<reference>(*this);
    }

    pointer operator->() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<pointer>(this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    It it;
    It* itp = &it;
    std::cout << *****(itp)->get_i() << "\n"; //ERROR
}
```

Both GCC and Clang++ somehow fail to invoke either of `operator*` or `operator->`, so I get an error `It doesn't have member function 'get_i'` in the last line regardless how many indirections I try. Does the standard warrant such unintuitive behavior?

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` from `It` to `El` is undefined behavior. Even if you get it to compile, there's no guarantee that the generated code will work.

Comment: Bonus question: how to do this in a way that doesn't invoke UB? I have some data and I want to have two views of it.

Comment: @jons34yp: why not just make `It` derive from `El`, perhaps privately? Basically you're going out of your way (and breaking strict aliasing) just to stop someone calling `get_i()` on an `It`. But maybe in your real code, `El` has some operators that clash with those of `It`. Normally you write iterators to refer to elements rather than each element being its own iterator, so I guess something funny is going on.

Comment: In the actual code `El` is itself an iterator - it refers to data which can not be represented as an object. Anyway, thanks for suggestion, it's a good improvement.

Answer (score 5):

Operator precedence: `->` binds more tightly, so is applied to the pointer `itp`.

When you overload `operator->`, that *doesn't* affect the meaning of `operator->` applied to a pointer-to-your-class. You want `(*itp)->get_i();`, I think.